# Kibana Dashboard only mode

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard, kibana-6

I have assigned a Kibana-dashboard-only-mode to a user, to only access my dashboard. In my dashboard I have saved a search result, so the user with the dashboard-only-mode role should be also able to see and explore. 
The problem is that when that user signs in, there is no data available in the dashboard.

The user can see the dashboard and the name of the dashboard and name of the saved search result, but when click on it, it says 'No results found' or 'No results displayed because all values equal 0' for visualizations. 
I already checked the 'time range', but nothing happened.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, the solution is that I also need to grant the user access to the underlying Elasticseach indices that contain the data that's used by the Visualizations.
Therefore, I created another role, in which I granted the user read access to the Elasticsearch indices that contain the data.

Comment: This is also documented in the [Kibana docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-dashboard-mode-configuration.html) though it is a little hidden — I think there is an open issue to fix this.